# Generic.xaml Invalid XAML Error

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, generic.xaml

For example, I have 2 custom control.

`A.cs` and `B.cs`

In `Generic.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:A}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:A}">
                <local:B/> <-- Invalid XAML Error
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And there is no Style of B

B is inherit `ContentPresenter`

When I build project, I got Invalid XAML Error, but it was builded dll file already.

And if I use it for other project.

It will get `StackOverflowException` in `WindowsBase.dll`

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is exactly without knowing the markup and code of A and B, if you can add those that would help.

Comment: It's my mistake. I put `local:B` into a `ItemTemplate` in my code. And it doesn't support `ContentPresenter`.